# DESCRIBE WHY DIRECT ORDERS FOLLOWED BY THE NAME OF TABLES

Tags: sql

DESCRIBE WHY DIRECT ORDERS FOLLOWED BY THE NAME OF TABLES ?

Example :
DESC CLASS_3C

why not

DESC TABLE CLASS_3C ?

Comment: DESCRIBE WHY OP SHOUTING ?

Comment: I just want to know why

Comment: don't understand your question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hi,
 If you see the key word **DESC** the meaning is **describe** . In a common word if you need describe any thing, you will provide the structure. For example, if you need to describe a car, you will say the entire attributes (parts) of car rather than describing each seperately. Like wise in database, describe (**DESC**) is denoted to tables by default. While describing a table, it provides you entire attributes like data type, length or any constraints.  So you no need to provide **table** key word. In a SQL language **DESC** key word is coded to refer a table.

Comment: SQL's desc means descending, and is used in ORDER BY.

Comment: DESC is a key word in SQL that will act, by meance of where it is provided.**DESC** table name provides you the structure of table. If you are sorting the data , use desc beside order by clause which act as descending function

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your DBMS, but using Oracle as an example, the reason is simply because that is the syntax of the `DESCRIBE` command. Per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve019.htm#SQPUG040), the syntax is:

```
DESC[RIBE] {[schema.]object[@db_link]}
```

Different commands can have different syntax. For example, the (simplified) syntax for dropping a table is, per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9003.htm):

```
DROP TABLE tableName;
```

Note that while the `DROP` statement includes the `TABLE` keyword, the `DESCRIBE` command does not. That's just the way the DBMS is designed.